# Should we add a tag called android-menu?

Tags: discussion, tag-creation

I've been working on improving the android tag wikis. I noticed that there are a lot of questions that use the [menu](/questions/tagged/menu) tag within the [android](/questions/tagged/android) hub(?). Menus in Android are pretty different from most other environments (and I've worked in quite a few). We have also established a standard pattern of prefixing android- to android specific topics. Since there isn't one already in use, I figured it would be best to bring it up here.

Oh yeah... And just to be sure, should I use 5 vote-ups to indicate a "yes"? Or will an answer be posted?

Comment: Actually, I must have overlooked it in the overwhelming list of android- tags. Don't know why I didn't just type [android-menu] in the search box.

Answer (score 1):

You can always [**create the tag**](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) if you have the right [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags).

> However note that: new tags will be automatically culled and removed from the system if they are not used by at least **1 other question** in a **6 month period**.

Comment: @Bart I updated my answer from the description of the privilege.